# how to backup wamp server

Tags: windows, backup

What's the best way of creating a full backup of my WAMP server and all of the data including wikis etc?

Can I simply sync the C:\wamp directory to an external drive?

Comment: You mean you have a production server running Wamp ?

Comment: I have wampserver 2.0 running on my local windows PC.  I don't know a great deal about how it all works to be honest - I just don't want to lose my wiki in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since WAMP applications do not provide their own backup APIs, you need to stop all services if you want to take a full file-system level backup; otherwise you'll get a lot of "file locked" errors and/or your backups will be in an incoherent state.

So yes, you can just make a copy of your C:\wamp directory, but stop all your WAMP-related services before (and remember to restart them after).

Answer (score 0):

You could run the server on a virtual machine and back it up regularly without the need to restart services.